# Hide/Show HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have an HTML document which contains tables. Some tables are subtables of other ones. You can have an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/juf5603f/3/):

HTML :

```
<table class='top'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>TopLevel</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub1'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub2'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 2</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub2'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 2</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub1'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub2'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 2</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='top'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>TopLevel</td>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub1'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>I</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 0px 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #AAA;
}

.greyrow{
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

td{
    width: 100px;
}

.top{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sub1{
    display: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;                
}

.sub2{
    display: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I would like to have only the toplevel tables displayed as default. This can be done with the css property "display: none".

I would like to show the subtables when the user clicks on the upper level table. Any existing jquery script for this ?

Comment: `"Any existing jquery script for this ?"` - You mean like `.hide()` and `.show()` in the base jQuery library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/juf5603f/6/) with what you're asking for. You can create as many subtables as you could possibly want, this code will still work, and it's light on the fiddle.

*HTML edit*: I've surrounded the table you're cascading from, and the tables being cascaded from it in a div tag with the class ". clickable" `<div class="clickable">...</div>`

*CSS edit*: I've set all ".clickable" children with the same class (`.clickable>.clickable{...}`) to `display:none;`

*JS edit*: The code is activated when you click on the immediate child table element. It then gets that table's parent and finds its immediate child with the ".clickable" class and slideToggles it (you can set a different effect if you'd like, I assumed that this was the look you wanted)

**HTML**

```
<div class="clickable">
    <table class='top'>
        <tr class='greyrow'>
            <td>TopLevel</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="clickable">
        <table class='sub1'>
            <tr class='greyrow'>
                <td>SubLevel 1</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="clickable">
            <table class='sub2'>
                <tr class='greyrow'>
                    <td>SubLevel 2</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class='sub2'>
                <tr class='greyrow'>
                    <td>SubLevel 2</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clickable">
        <table class='sub1'>
            <tr class='greyrow'>
                <td>SubLevel 1</td>
                <td>E</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="clickable">
            <table class='sub2'>
                <tr class='greyrow'>
                    <td>SubLevel 2</td>
                    <td>F</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clickable">
    <table class='top'>
        <tr class='greyrow'>
            <td>TopLevel</td>
            <td>G</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="clickable">
        <table class='sub1'>
            <tr class='greyrow'>
                <td>SubLevel 1</td>
                <td>H</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='greyrow'>
                <td>SubLevel 1</td>
                <td>I</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 0px 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #AAA;
}
.greyrow {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
}
.top {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.sub1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.sub2 {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.clickable {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.clickable>.clickable {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".clickable").children("table").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children(".clickable").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Even better than what I was looking for! Thank you very much. Detailed explanation is also nice. I will try to understand exactly how this works.

Comment: If you have any questions about it feel free to ask, I'm more than happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf89fkm7/) to do this. Is this what you are looking for?

HTML:

```
<table class='top' id='A'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>TopLevel</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<table class='sub1 sub_A' id='A1'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr> 
</table> 
<table class='sub2 sub_A1'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 2</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<table class='sub2 sub_A1'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 2</td>
        <td>D</td></tr>
</table>
<table class='sub1 sub_A' id='A2'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<table class='sub2 sub_A2'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 2</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
<table class='top' id='G'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>TopLevel</td>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='sub1 sub_G'>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='greyrow'>
        <td>SubLevel 1</td>
        <td>I</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-width: 0px 0;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #AAA;
    }

    .greyrow{
        background-color: #c7c7c7;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        font-family: Verdana;
    }

    td{
        width: 100px;
    }

    .top{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .sub1{
        display: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
        width: 200px;
    }

    .sub2{
        display: none;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 200px;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var Clicks = [];
function click(id, numClicks) {
    this.id = id;
    this.numClicks = numClicks;
}
$(".top").click(function() {
    var access = -1;
    for (var c=0;c<Clicks.length;c++) {
        if (Clicks[c].id === this.id) {
            Clicks[c].numClicks += 1;
            access = c;
            c = Clicks.length;
        }
    }
    if (access === -1) {
        access = Clicks.length;
        Clicks.push(new click(this.id, 1));
    }
    if (Clicks[access].numClicks % 2 !== 0) {
        $((".sub_"+(this.id))).css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $((".sub_"+(this.id)+'1')).css("display", "none");
        $((".sub_"+(this.id))).css("display", "none");
    }
});
$(".sub1").click(function() {
    id = this.id;
    var access = -1;
    for (var c=0;c<Clicks.length;c++) {
        if (Clicks[c].id === id) {
            Clicks[c].numClicks += 1;
            access = c;
            c = Clicks.length;
        }
    }
    if (access === -1) {
        access = Clicks.length;
        Clicks.push(new click(this.id, 1));
    }
    if (Clicks[access].numClicks % 2 !== 0) {
        $((".sub_"+(id))).css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $((".sub_"+(id))).css("display", "none");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply ! Two things : I also need to hide the sub tables when the user clicks on the same table again. And there is no limit on the number of subtables. I can probably figure out how to hide them back but I have no idea on how to have a smart handling of a lot of sub levels.

Comment: Oh, I guess for the collapse, you could add in some counters to see if the table is being clicked for the first or second time. However, I just hard-coded all the needed ids and classes into the HTML. Maybe someone else will post a better idea :)